# Чи залишається вживаним слово забудовець?

Tags: вживання-слів, синоніми

В  Російсько-українському академічному словнику 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов) як відповідник російського *застройщик* наводиться іменник *забудовець*. Але такого слова немає ані у Тлумачному словнику української мови в 11 т., ані у СЛОВНИКУ УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ МОВИ ONLINE. Натомість із тим же значенням є іменник *забудовник*:

> **ЗАБУДО́ВНИК**, а, ч. *Той, хто щось споруджує, забудовує якусь територію.*
>   [Соняшник:] Ану, скажи.., Фіногене, – чому в цементі піску багато,
>   чому дачні забудовники до тебе вчащають? (Л. Дмитерко); Відкрилася в
>   Держбанку позика для індивідуальних забудовників. Взяв і я собі таку
>   позику – заходився ставити невеличкий дім (В. Логвиненко); Ходив [дід]
>   по “халтурах”, парове опалення забудовникам ставив, дахи вкривав
>   трудно добутим шифером (О. Гончар); Міністерство архітектури та інші
>   відомства зобов'язані розробити заходи щодо підтримки індивідуальних
>   забудовників з числа депортованих (з газ.); // *Організація, яка
>   займається спорудженням певного будівельного об'єкта на замовлення.*
>   Забудовник погодився переробити каналізаційну систему в новобудівлі
>   (із журн.); Квартири за цінами від забудовника! (з мови реклами).

Чи слово *забудовець* досі функціонує в українській мові і чи можна його вживати як синонім до усталеного *забудовник*?

Comment: Problem z [narostkom](//r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovotvir_narostky) ne baču: 30. […] а) при дієслівних пнях на означення носія чинности або об’єкта її; […]; іноді й чергується з **-ак**, **-ач** а то й із **-ок** тощо: *співець — співак — підспівач, коханець — коханок, **промовець** — **промовник***...; особливо часто вживається в **-о́вець**: *службо́вець, урядо́вець, народо́вець*...

Answer (score 2):

Наткнувся на статтю "**[Назви осіб за родом діяльності в українській перекладній лексикографії 1918–1933 рр.](http://eprints.zu.edu.ua/21511/1/tom_lex.pdf)**", де пише:

> Чимало в словниках зафіксовано назв осіб за родом діяльності, що 
>   **сьогодні  мають  інші  відповідники**.  У  частини  сучасних найменувань
>   простежується вплив російської мови:... забудовець [КЄ] (рос. 
>   застройщик) – забудовник;...

Та й відсутність цього слова у СУМ11 і СУМ20 свідчить про те, що воно вже не вживається. Натомість, в обох словниках є слово "забудовник".